# How to modify the already built object in Java, when the Object is built using Builder Pattern?

Tags: java, object, builder

I have built (Using `Builder` Pattern) an Employee object with three fields `Name`, `Age` and `Gender`.

```
public class Employee {

    private String name;
    private String age;
    private String gender;

    // Constructor
    private Employee(Builder builder) {
        this.name = builder.name;
        this.age = builder.age;
        this.gender = builder.gender;
    }

    // Employee Builder
    public static class Builder {
        private String name;
        private String age;
        private String gender;

        public Builder name(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder age(String age) {
            this.age = age;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder gender(String gender) {
            this.gender = gender;
            return this;
        }
    }

    // Getters
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
}
```

Now in the Following Class I have built my Employee Object,

```
public class TestEmployee {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Employee employee = new                Employee.Builder().age("23").gender("Male").name("John").build();

        System.out.println("Name : " + employee.getName());
        System.out.println("Age : " + employee.getAge());
        System.out.println("Gender : " + employee.getGender());
    }
}
```

How can I modify the Age of the Employee "John" by breaking the already built employee object?

FYI : I don't want to have `Setters` in my `Employee` object.

Comment: Reflection is an option?

Comment: No, he definitely shouldn't use reflection.

Comment: @Kayaman builder is used to create immutable objects.. when you say builder I trust you and assume its immutable.. I do not see other way to modify immutable objects..

Comment: There's a logical flaw with creating immutable objects and then modifying them via reflection. Just because you can do it doesn't mean you should. If you want to modify an object that you have created, don't make it immutable.

Comment: It is a question that deny itself. The author don't understond what he asked about. IE: How can I eat the apple, and have the same apple in my hand after that?

Comment: @Kayaman Ofc, I don't say its good practice, but if you do not have any other solution.. (as he said he cannot  or do not want to add setters)

Comment: Where did the `build` method come from? I don't see a trace of a implementation.

Comment: @Serhiy He's the one who decided to make the object immutable by using the builder pattern, so he's just confused.

Comment: @Kayaman true, I have not read with attention the first sentence.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to modify an immutable object. Do you see the problem there?

Either add setters (or any methods that mutate the state) or accept that the object is immutable.

You can of course create a new object based on the values of the old one, but it won't be the same object then.

Comment: I agree with you. Thanks for the information. Now I understand.

Answer (score 4):

ahh I was also trying to solve my problem with this approach and ironically I stumbled upon this question. I understand the challenge here, we are trying to modify an object with same builder setters but doing so we'll end up with an new object.

I figured out that there is a solution, so after approx 5yrs here's my answer LOL(to someone who's gonna end up here)

first, instead of creating duplicate properties of OuterClass in inner static Builder class. *declare an instance of outer class in Builder class. which means your build() method will return that instance.

this *declaration of instance is intended, as I am planning to create it internally or gonna ask for its memory from outside.

```
public class Employee {

    private String name;
    private String age;
    private String gender;


    public Static Builder builder()
    {
       return new Builder();
    }

    public Static Builder modifier(Employee employee)
    {
       return new Builder(employee);
    }


    // Employee Builder
    public static class Builder {
        private Employee employee;

        public Builder(Employee employee)
        {
           this.employee = employee;
        } 

        public Builder()
        {
           this.employee = new Employee();
        }

        public Builder name(String name) {
            this.employee.name = name;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder age(String age) {
            this.employee.age = age;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder gender(String gender) {
            this.gender = gender;
            return this;
        }

        public Employee build()
        {
           return this.employee;
        }
    }

    // Getters
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
}
```

notice the tweak here, I introduced a modifier that takes Employee object and further allows client to modify it with Builder pattern.
So your client will use it like this...

to create new Employee

```
Employee employee = Employee.builder().name("abc).age(20).build();
```

to modify same instance

```
Employee.modifier(employee)
        .name("xyz")
        .build();
```

Comment: This is ok, but are we not loosing the key property of immutability of the object here?
and also, since we are allowing them to modify the existing object..then why not introduce the setter in the object itself?

Answer (score 3):

Build another one using Copy-On-Write (reuse existing fields but change age).

```
Employee.Builder()
     .age(employee.getAge() + 1)
     .gender(employee.getGender())
     .name(employee.getName())
     .build();
```

Keep in mind, it will be another object.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to put setters (and make Employee mutable) you can't modify age of john... instead of this, what you can do is:

```
employee = new Employee.Builder()
                       .age("21")
                       .gender(employee.getGender())
                       .name(employee.getName())
                       .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want setters or public non-final fields, then you can add an extra constructor to the builder which will cause an initial state matching the instance, but with the builder setters available.  This won't modify the original object, but create a new one based on it.

```
public static class Builder {
    private String name;
    private String age;
    private String gender;

    public Builder(Employee employee) {
        this.name = employee.getName();
        this.age = employee.getAge();
        this.gender = employee.getGender();
    }

    public Builder name(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder age(String age) {
        this.age = age;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder gender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
        return this;
    }

    public Employee build() {
        return new Employee(this);
    }
}
```

You can then use it as following.

```
Employee employee = new Employee.Builder().age("23").gender("Male").name("John").build();
Employee employee2 = new Employee.Builder(employee).name("Jane").build();
```